# Thickness of pgfplot line makes data look jagged

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

I am using matlab2tikz to generate a plot from experimental data and have a problem with the appearance of the plot. Changing the line thickness makes the data look very jagged. This is hard to describe and so I have attached two plots, one with `line width` set to 0.1pt and the other with the `line width` set to 0.8pt.

[image: Fig1]
[image: Fig2]

The thicker line is noticeably more jagged, and more importantly, the line is no longer an accurate representation of the data (the data does not jump as high or low).

In fact, this effect is also present for the thinner line, but is not as noticeable. The actual data is not fully smooth, but with the scale chosen the oscillations should not be visible. The last plot is from Matlab, and the data looks normal there.

[image: Fig3]

How can I get a "good" output from PGFplots?

Comment: Hopefully this duplicate makes the issue more readily diagnosable.